# react useReducer hook on every dispatch use the initial state and not the updated one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the useReducer hook to manage the state but when i dispatch an action the reducer receive the right action with type and payload but the state is always the initial state and not the updated one...

REDUCER:
`
export const fasiInterventoReducer = (state: FasiInterventoState, action: FasiInterventoAvailableActions): FasiInterventoState => {
const {type, payload} = action;

```
switch (type) {
    case "UPDATE_SELECTED_IDS":
        return  {...state, selectedIds: payload};

    case "UPDATE_LAVORAZIONI_COUNT":
        return {...state, lavorazioniCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_DDT_COUNT":
        return {...state, ddtCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_MATERIALS_COUNT":
        return {...state, materialsCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_MEZZI_COUNT":
        return {...state, mezziCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_SPEDIZIONI_COUNT":
        return {...state, spedizioniCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_SPESE_COUNT":
        return {...state, speseCounter: payload};
    case "UPDATE_VARIE_COUNT":
        return {...state, varieCounter: payload};
    
    case "UPDATE_IS_LAVORAZIONI_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isLavorazioniSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_DDT_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isDdtSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_MATERIALS_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isMaterialsSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_MEZZI_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isMezziSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_SPEDIZIONI_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isSpedizioniSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_SPESE_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isSpeseSectionCompacted: payload};
    case "UPDATE_IS_VARIE_SECTION_COMPACTED":
        return {...state, isVarieSectionCompacted: payload};

    default:
        return state;
}
```

}`

CUSTOM HOOK THAT KEEPS USE REDUCER IMPLEMENTATIONS:

```
const useInterventiState = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(fasiInterventoReducer, initialState);
    
    const toggleIsSectionCompacted = (section2Toggle: CompactableSection) => {
        switch (section2Toggle) {
            case 'materiali':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_MATERIALS_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isMaterialsSectionCompacted});
            case 'ddt':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_DDT_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isDdtSectionCompacted});
            case 'lavorazioni':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_LAVORAZIONI_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isLavorazioniSectionCompacted});
            case 'mezzi':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_MEZZI_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isMezziSectionCompacted});
            case 'spedizioni':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_SPEDIZIONI_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isSpedizioniSectionCompacted});
            case 'spese':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_SPESE_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isSpeseSectionCompacted});
            case 'varie':
                return dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_IS_VARIE_SECTION_COMPACTED', payload: !state.isVarieSectionCompacted});
        
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return {
        state,
        dispatch,
        toggleIsSectionCompacted
    };
};

The implementation seems to be right because resucììducer receive the right actions but it doesn't keep the updated state...
```

Comment: Hi. Please read up on how to make a [mre]. There is so much code here that's not needed.

Comment: Maybe the component remounts every time you change the state

Comment: I edited it removing exceeding parts, hope that it is more clear and readable

Comment: I catch that the component was remounting every time but I don't understand why...

Comment: You have to add the entire component and it's parent. You can try creating a codesanbox